# how to pick the latest record from a table and insert into another table

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

I have a scenario where I have to create a replication of a target table along with source Id field.

If I have Target Table with columns :

```
Target_ID,
name,
createdate which is getdate()
```

Then  my target replication table will be:

```
 Target_ID,
 name,
 createdate which is getdate(),
source_ID
```

Once the record hits the target table , I want the record to be inserted into replication table along with source Id. I can do this and it is working. but I would like to include the condition that only if record is inserted in target then insert in replication table else do not do anything.As of now I am picking up the latest record from target and inserting into replication table. What if there is no record inserted , even then my code would pick the latest record and insert into replication table. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause on first statement to get inserted.Target_ID, it will return DBNULL if no record inserted.
Then use [SQL Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx) to Rollback action if first insert fail.